# Retrieving data from Sqlite database and plot it in XY graph for android

Tags: android, sqlite, graph

Is there any existing codes that allows data to be retrieved from SQLite database and displayed it in graph? (I want the graph to be plotted x (integer headcount) against y (String department.) The following code only allows coordinates to be manually entered in the class file.

```java
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Vector<SeriesData> sds = new Vector<SeriesData>();
    //line
    SeriesData sd = new SeriesData();       
    sd.setData(new double[][]{{0,0}, {2, 2}, {4, 4}, {8, 8}});
    sds.add(sd);
    //bar
    SeriesData sd2 = new SeriesData();      
    sd2.setData(new double[][]{{0,0}, {2, 2}, {4, 4}, {8, 8}});
    sd2.series.bars.show = true;
    sds.add(sd2);


    FlotDraw fd = new FlotDraw(sds, null, null);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    FlotChartContainer tv = (FlotChartContainer)this.findViewById(R.id.flotdraw);
    if(tv != null) {
        tv.setDrawData(fd);
    }

}
```